# More limits and derivatives, can I do this?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Here is the given problem:

Suppose $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=-1$. Evaluate the following limit if it exists:

$$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(2h)+f(3h)-f(4h)+...+f(2013h)}{h}$$

So what I was thinking was to split it up so you have,

$$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h} + \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(3h)-f(2h)}{h}+...+\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(2013h)-f(2012h)}{h}$$

So the first part is equal to $0$ and the rest is MVT and you get

$$f'(c_1)+...+f'(c_{1006})$$

which each would equal $-1$ and total $-1006$. Is this correct?

Comment: $$-1+2-3+4.....-2013=-1007$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $\lambda$ be a constant. Then
$$ \lim_{h\to 0} {f(\lambda h)\over h} = \lambda \lim_{h\to 0} {f(h)\over h} = \lambda f'(0) = -\lambda.$$
Now sum it up.  Notice this still works if $\lambda = 0$; you see this separately since the division done here would be illegal in that case.

Comment: but the question is $h \to \infty$,  I think it might be $h \to 0$ but it may be have limitation when $h  \to \infty$ also.

Comment: I can only attempt to answer the question that is put to me

Comment: OK, the question is changed. so you are right.

Comment: @chenbai yeah sorry! I wrote it wrong the first time. So what I did works when h approaches 0? :)

Comment: @ncmathsadist so what I did was wrong?

Comment: the right answer should be -1007 as first part is -1. ncmathsadist's answer is nice for you.

Comment: @ncmathsadist: just wanted to add one step in your derivation so that it is clear enough because your existing answer led to some confusion between me and mathematics2x2life. He thought that you got $\lambda$ out of limit operation using L'Hospital. However the correct step is $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(\lambda h)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\lambda\cdot\frac{f(\lambda h) - f(0)}{\lambda h} = \lambda\cdot f'(0)$$

Answer (score 1):

This is much easier than it looks. Notice that if you let $h=0$ in the first limit, you obtain $0/0$. This means that you can apply l'Hopital's rule and make this easier on yourself. Differentiating the top and bottom with respect to $h$ yields
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f'(h)-2f'(2h)+3f'(3h)-\cdots+2013f'(2013h)}{1}
$$
Letting $h \to 0$ and using the fact that $f'(0)=-1$, you have 
$$
-1+2-3+4-\cdots-2013
$$
which is $-1007$--as in nemathsadist's answer.

Comment: Sorry to say, but L'Hospital can't be applied here. One must know the conditions for L'Hospital before applying it. Here we are only given about $f'(0)$ and not that $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of zero. I hope you understand your mistake.

Comment: To mathematics2x2life: How can you conclude that $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $0$ from the fact that $f'(0)$ exists? If you really think so please provide a proof.

Comment: Saying that it is immediate is not a proof of what you say. You need to get rid of the misconceptions on this particular point. Differntiability at a point guarantees that function is continuous at that point. It does not even guarantee the continuity in the neighborhood of the point, let alone differentiability.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11738/discussion-between-paramanand-singh-and-mathematics2x2life)

Answer (score 0):

You solved it, but your own solution has a little problem.

You considered $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h}$ to be zero, but you must know that the expression is in $\frac00$ form, so to evaluate that part, you have to use L'Hopital rule or any other rule you wish to use to find its value.

Applying L'Hopital, we get, $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f'(h)}{1}$ or $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f'(0)}{1}$. Its value is -1.

Comment: Sorry to say, but L'Hospital can't be applied here. One must know the conditions for L'Hospital before applying it. Here we are only given about f′(0) and not that f is differentiable in a neighborhood of zero. I hope you understand your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

ncmathsadist has already given a perfect answer. I want to highlight the issue with your approach. A derivative $f'(0) = -1$ means that $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = -1$$ It does not mean that $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(3h) - f(2h)}{h} = -1$$ (in fact this limit might not even exist). Hence your split does not work. Note the way ncmathsadist uses $f(0) = 0$ in each term and that leads to the derivative so that the final answer is $-1+2-3 + \cdots - 2013$

Comment: can the downvoter explain the reason for downvote.